# Parameterize call to method name

Tags: java

I've a below class

```
public class OtherString {

    private String underlyingString;

    public OtherString(String inp) {
        this.underlyingString = inp;
    }

    public String checkAplhaNumeric(String underlyingString) {
        
        String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
        return this.underlyingString.matches(pattern) ? "Y" : "N";

    }

    public String checkInteger(String underlyingString) {
        
        String pattern= "^[0-9]*$";
        return this.underlyingString.matches(pattern) ? "Y" : "N";

    }

    public String checkString(String underlyingString) {
        
        String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z]*$";
        return this.underlyingString.matches(pattern) ? "Y" : "N";

    }

}
```

Is there any way I could decide method to be called at run time for OtherString  instance ?

For example:

If `String methodName = checkInteger;`
then call `otherStringInstance.checkInteger(inp);`

Comment: You *could* use reflection, but it is almost always better not to do this. For this, I recommend that you look up and use the Command Design Pattern.